# Проблема с асинхронностью

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет.
Есть такой код:

```js
<template>

  <section class="center_content_firmenistorie">
    
      <h2 id="admin_id_h2_1" class="h2_1 admin_class">
        {{ $store.state.dbFirmenistorieData.data | get_h2_data }}
      </h2>

  </section>
  <!--   <section class="center_content_firmenistorie">    end    -->

</template>


<script>

  export default{

  data: function () {
    return {

      maxYearData: this.get_max_year_data(),

    }
  },

  methods: {

    get_max_year_data: function () {

      let firmenistorieYearsArray = [];

      const dbFirmenistorieData = this.$store.state.dbFirmenistorieData.data.company_history_data;

      for (let i = 0; i < dbFirmenistorieData.length; i++) {
        firmenistorieYearsArray.push(Number(dbFirmenistorieData[i].company_history_from_year));
      }

      let maxYearData = Math.max.apply(Math, firmenistorieYearsArray);
      this.maxYearData = String(maxYearData);
      return String(maxYearData);

    },

  },

  filters: {

    get_h2_data(value){

      let filterH2Data = '';

      for (let i = 0; i < value.company_history_data.length; i++) {
        if( value.company_history_data[i].company_history_from_year == this.maxYearData){
          filterH2Data = value.company_history_data[i].company_history_from_year;
          console.log(filterH2Data);
        }
      }

      return filterH2Data;
    },
  },

}

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Мне не нужно точное решение проблемы - я понимаю что тяжело вникать в код когда его много - но мне необходим совет:

во время запуска функции фильтра я сталкиваюсь с проблемой того что метод или же если этот метод ложить в дату - не удается идентифицировать внутри тела функции фильтра.

Вопрос:
Как наиболее правильно решать проблемы с асинхронностью такого рода?
(что только не пробовал делать - ниче не помагает.)

Comment: Вы знаете, это наверное самое важное предложение, но оно совершенно непонятно: *во время запуска функции фильтра я сталкиваюсь с проблемой того что метод или же если этот метод ложить в дату - не удается идентифицировать внутри тела функции фильртра.*

Comment: метод возвращает строку '2017' и результат работы этого метода не идентифицируется внутри тела фильтра.(происходит ошибка)
такая формулировка понятна?
Если же я вместо метода подставляю строку '2017'
http://joxi.ru/4AkL5KoHozJ6Nr
то у меня нет никаких проблем - сам фильтр как видим работает нормально.

+ сам метод(как можно увидеть в дебаггере) тоже работает нормально в этом варианте и возвращает в дату необходимое значение.
http://joxi.ru/KAg5e6oHE8yvOm